# DataGridView columnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Padding отдельно на каждую колонку

Tags: c#, winforms

Можно добавить общий Padding на все колонки, но можно ли задать его для каждого заголовка колонки отдельно?

Как на строки:
`Column1.DefaultCellStyle.Padding = new Padding(30, 0, 0, 0);`
`Column2.DefaultCellStyle.Padding = new Padding(25, 0, 0, 0);`

Пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уже точно не могу сказать, но кмк можно, если обращаться к каждому Row и устанавливать ему паддинг. Главное не забыть вызвать перерисовку элемента, иначе все изменения не будут иметь эффект.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для заголовка

```cs
dataGridView1.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderCell.Style.Padding = new Padding(30, 0, 0, 0);
dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderCell.Style.Padding = new Padding(25, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Я знаю что можно использовать это свойство, что я и отметил в названии вопроса. Мне нужно для каждой колонки изменить Padding заголовка отдельно. Чего с `DataGridView.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle` добиться невозможно, т.к. он меняет на все колонки.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос.

Comment: @Алексей да, так понятнее, обновил ответ

Comment: То что нужно! Большое тебе спасибо.